# How set Locale in Time Picker Android

Tags: android, timepicker

I am developing the multi-language supported app. so I want to set Locale.US in time picker when I changed language English to Arabic.

[image]

I want to show an English time picker.

I want to pass Locale.US in time picker, now I'm pass locale.US in Date Picker but how can I pass in time picker?